# Cannot solve the sysmbol Theme from import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.Theme;

Tags: java, android, firebase, androidx

Am developing an android app and I really want it to use affollested matrial dialogs specifically the theme class. When I try to import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.Theme; In this class, I get an error cannot resolve symbol theme please help.
this is my imports

```java
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog;
import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.Theme;
```

```java
@Override
public void showProgress() {
    materialDialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(LoginChamaActivity.this)
            .title(R.string.progress_dialog_title)
            .theme(Theme.DARK)
            .content(R.string.please_wait)
            .progress(true, 0)
            .show();
    chamaLoginRecycler.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```